# decrease size of icon in jetpack compose to match row height

Tags: android, icons, android-jetpack-compose, modifier, composable

I have the following composable.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Temp() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello", fontSize = 10.sp)
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Star,
            contentDescription = "Star",
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
        )
    }
}
```

The height of icon is not decreasing from 24.dp. Is there any way I can achieve this behavior. I want the icon size to just be the height of the parent row.
If the text is large. The icons size is increased. I think it has to be with icon minimum size being 24.dp. How can I make icon smaller?

Comment: I don't know how, but I look at the code. Icon use `DefaultIconSizeModifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)` if imageVector passed. otherwise uses painter size. So try add vector asset with the required size and then use like `Icon(painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_star_10)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code actually works as expected - that's how intrinsic calculations work.

Compose checks the min height of each view and chooses the maximum of those values. In your case, the min height of the image is related to the intrinsic size of the image, which you cannot control in the case of `Icons.Default`.

A possible solution is to use `Modifier.layout`. When Compose calculates the intrinsic height, the height constraint will be infinite, in which case you can layout it as a zero size view, so that your text will be the highest. When the intrinsic height is determined, you can measure and position the icon:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Red)
        .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
        .fillMaxWidth()
) {
    Text(text = "Hello", fontSize = 10.sp)
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Star,
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                if (constraints.maxHeight == Constraints.Infinity) {
                    layout(0, 0) {}
                } else {
                    val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
                    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                        placeable.place(0, 0)
                    }
                }
            }
    )
}
```

Using `Modifier.layout` you can change size of view and its position. Usually you use it like this:

1. First parameter, `measurable` is an object on which you can call `measure` with `constraints` - the second `layout` parameter. `measure` is gonna calculate the size your view will take, taking `constraints` in count.
2. in `layout` you need to pass the desired view size - usually it can be taken from `placeable` from the previous step.
3. inside `layout` you need to call `place` on the `placeable` with the desired offset.

With `height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` `layout` content is getting called multiple times:

1. during the first call(s) max height constraint is equal to `Infinity`, so intrinsic calculations can select the correct size ignoring the parent size.
2. In the last call max height constraint is equal to the calculated parent intrinsic height.

In my code during first calls, when height constraint is equal to `Infinity`, I say that this view has zero size, so it's not counted in intrinsic measurements. When intrinsic height is defined, I can layout it with the final constraints.

Comment: This worked.. thanks.. could you please explain me what are we doing actually?

Comment: @DikenMhrz I added more detailed explanation

Comment: I have been looking at many a Stack Overflow post, but finally this question and answer are exactly what I needed. Thank you Diken for posting the question and thank you @PhilDukhov for the great answer and thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can "reset" the icon's intrinsic size with

```
Modifier.fillMaxHeight().height(1.dp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I took @Phil's answer and turned it into an extension which in turn can be reused.

```kotlin
fun Modifier.matchRowSize() : Modifier {
    return layout { measurable, constraints ->
        if (constraints.maxHeight == Constraints.Infinity) {
            layout(0, 0) {}
        } else {
            val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
            layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                placeable.place(0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which can be used in your icon like so:

```kotlin
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
        .padding(8.dp)
) {
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Star,
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .matchRowSize() // <-- here
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(10.dp))
    Text(text = "Hello", fontSize = 17.sp)
}
```